# What is share/webkitgtk/databases/indexeddb/v1?

Tags: backup

When I did a backup using deja-dup it did not backup /home/paul/.local/share**/webkitgtk**/databases/indexeddb/v1. This is the first time this has happened. What is this webkitgtk? Is this a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WebKitGTK is a web-browser engine. Some apps use it to display local and remote web-pages. Some modern websites require local storage. This local storage is saved in SQLite format in the mentioned directories.

So it is cache, you can skip its backup creation.